# Redirecting multilingual url

Tags: seo, url, multilingual, redirect

I'm having a hard time redirecting URLs on multilingual Joomla site.

New site has following URL structure: `http://sitename.com/[language]/[pagename].html` and old site URL structure is as follows : `http://sitename.com/[pagename]?lang=[language]`.

I have tried several regex incantations but none of them work. It seems like Joomla multilingual rewrites are overriding them somehow.

Here's one of the regexes I've used, I have tried with redirect as well:

```
RewriteRule /(.+)\?lang=(.+) /$2/$1.html [L,R=301]
```

It just doesn't work no matter how I put it and I want to redirect old URLs to new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm by no means a .htaccess guru, but here's an idea that might work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*lang=en.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*lang=es.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /es/$1.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*lang=no.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /no/$1.html? [R=301,L]
```

You'll have to repeat the two lines for each language you want to redirect, but it shouldn't be difficult unless you have a crazy amount of languages.

The first rule checks if `lang=en` is present in the URL, and if it is, the URL is rewritten using `/en/` in the path. The `?` in `html?` removes any URL parameter. The `L` parameter forces the rule to be the last one, and any rule below is ignored.

You can test this (and other solutions) using the **[htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)**.

Hope it helps, at least it's worth a try.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing something similar with ReDJ component in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a tool called Mod Rewrite Generator (http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php).

It's a tool that allows you to insert any URL with parameters (domain.com/index.php?lang=en), then choose how you want to use them in the final url, and then gives you the code for your `.htaccess` file.

I find it usefull in many situations.