# Nginx infinite redirect loop with multilingual Joomla

Tags: multilingual, nginx, server-configuration

I'm busy trying to move a Joomla site to a new server.  I want to host with Nginx.

As an intermediate step before swapping the live site I'm hosting it under a temporary new domain name.

When I try to load the site I get an infinite redirect loop.  It is definitely reaching the Joomla index.php file because the redirect from the base path / to the language specific version /en/ is occurring.

I saw a similar question here: [Redirecting multilingual url](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5182/redirecting-multilingual-url) but I'm struggling to translate it into nginx config.

Edit: I don't think that this is an Nginx configuration problem.  Removing the system/languagefilter plugin lets the site load (albeit with a wrong template).  I've used scp to copy the directory between servers and mysqldump for the database so I can't see where the difference is?